# In Microsoft Word 2010, after I updated my Table of Contents, it is displaying a chart (from the document) how do I correct this?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

The Table of Contents link should just be to the heading on the page, which is the name of the chart. I don't know why it is bringing in the whole chart.

Answer (score 3):

You have probably accidentally styled the chart as a **heading** (the table of content will include all headings to a certain level).

To correct this, select the chart, apply the normal style (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> on Mac, <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> on Windows) and update the table of contents.